# REST will create a Representation of a resource or CREATE & TRANSFER a Representation of a Resource?

Tags: rest

So, it will create a representation or it will create and transfer a representation and browser will render the representation?

Comment: Can you explain what the difference (to you) is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useful definitions from Fielding's dissertation, which defined REST

- [Resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)
- [Representation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_2)

The information included in the body of an HTTP message is a representation, and it is a copy.

When you point your browser at https://stackoverflow.com/ , the server sends to you an HTML representation of the `https://stackoverflow.com/` resource, which the browser renders.

But the render part is not required.  For some media types, the browser will save the representation on disk, rather than trying to "render" it.

And of course a user agent like `curl` has only trivial rendering capabilities.